# What can be said about the solution to $Ax=b$ when $b$ is an eigenvector of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

If I have some eigenvector $b$ of some matrix $A$, which entails $Ab=\lambda b$, what can I say about the solution, $x$, to $Ax=b$?

My first solution, which seems very weak, is

$$ Ab = \lambda b, Ax = b $$
$$ AAx = \lambda b $$
$$ A^2 x = \lambda b $$

Since we know that eigenvectors of $A$ are also eigenvectors of $A^2, A^{-1}$ (or any function of $A$), and $b$ in the last line above is still an eigenvector of $A$, then $x = b$?

---

But I am pretty sure this fails because we don't know if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$? Though, $\lambda ^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$.. But I don't see how I can tie this in to fix the proposed solution above. I really feel like I need to invoke $det(A - \lambda I) x = 0$ for this to ever work out..

Comment: You can't claim $x=b$.  As a counterexample, consider something like the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&\lambda\end{pmatrix}$, $x=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$, $b=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$.  What you can say is that $\lambda x-b$ is in the kernel/ null space of $A$.

Comment: Upon multiplying both sides of $Ax=b$ by $\lambda$, we conclude that $\lambda x-b$ lies in the null space of $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\lambda \neq 0$, then rearranging gives
$$A \cdot \frac{1}{\lambda} b = \frac{1}{\lambda} A b = \frac{1}{\lambda} (\lambda b) = b,$$ so $x = \frac{1}{\lambda} b$ is a solution of $A x = b$. We can recover the full set of solutions as usual by adding solutions of the corresponding homogeneous equation, $A x = 0$. In particular, if $A$ is nondegenerate, the above solution is unique.

If $\lambda = 0$, there may or may not be a solution. If $0$ is not a defective eigenvalue (i.e., if its geometric and algebraic multiplicities agree), $A x = b$ has a solution only for $b = 0$. If $0$ is defective, then there will be a solution for some nonzero $b$ but not others. For example, take $A = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$ and analyze separately the cases $b = \pmatrix{1\\0}$ and $b = \pmatrix{0\\1}$.

Comment: Is there a way to obtain $x$ only in terms of $A, b$? That is, in my case I am only given $A, b$ but not $\lambda$. I could calculate $Ab = \lambda b$ and "guess", which is weak. // Hmm, would it suffice to use the Rayleigh quotient, knowing that at an eigenvector $v$ the Rayleigh quotient $R(v) = \frac{v^T Av}{v^T v} = \lambda_v $? Then simply invoke that $b$ is indeed an eigenvector of $A$?

Comment: Like I said in my answer, there may be infinitely many solutions, or there be no solution at all. If you know there is a single solution, then either of your methods works. There is no guessing in the first method: $A b = \lambda b$ is a perfectly good linear system and can be solved deterministically.

Answer (score 1):

Since $Ab = \lambda b$ one solution to $Ax = b$ is $x = \frac 1 \lambda b$.

If $x$ is any other solution then $A(x- \frac 1 \lambda b ) = 0$ so that $x- \frac 1 \lambda b$ belongs to the null space of $A$.

Observe $x = \frac 1 \lambda b + (x- \frac 1 \lambda b)$.

Thus any solution $x$ to $Ax = b$ has the form $x = \frac 1 \lambda y + n$, where $n \in N(A)$.

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to comment on the behavior in the case $\lambda = 0$ (which is both qualitatively different from the general case, and more varied)?